# List of domain contents not rendering on one GSP but is on another Grails

Tags: grails, rendering, gsp

Right so my codes for my test view is:

```html
    @Secured(["IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED", "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"])
    def list(){
        def allPosts = postService.getPosts()
    }
```

```html
<body>

<h1>Welcome to the main feed, <sec:loggedInUserInfo field="username" var="username"/></h2>

<g:if test="${flash.message}">
<div class="messageContainer">
  <div style="display: block">${flash.message}</div>
  </div>
</g:if>
<p/>
<div>
<g:each var="post" in="${allPosts}">
    <p>Last Name: ${post.content}</p>
    <p>First Name: ${post.content}</p>
</g:each>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this works,

This was just to test if there was another issue though as what I want it to work on is this:

```html
    @Secured(["IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED", "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"])
    def wall() {
        def allPosts = postService.getPosts()

        profile = springSecurityService.currentUser.getProfile()

        if(!profile){
            redirect(controller: "profile", action: "viewProfile")
        }else {
            [profile: profile]
        }


    }
```

and

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
         <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    </head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to the main feed, <sec:loggedInUserInfo field="username" var="username"/></h2>

<g:if test="${flash.message}">
<div class="messageContainer">
  <div style="display: block">${flash.message}</div>
  </div>
</g:if>
<p/>
<div>
    <h3>
        What are you thinking?
    </h3>
    </p>
    <div>
        <g:form action="addPost">
        <g:textArea class="postContent" id="postContent" name="content" rows="3" cols="50"/><br/>
        <g:submitButton class="postSubmit loginButton" name="post" value="Post"/>
        </g:form>
    <div>
</div><br/>
    <div class="PostContainer">
<g:each var="post" in="${allPosts}">
    <p>${post.content}</p>
    <p>${post.content}</p>
</g:each>
</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

but the posts and content will not render on the second example

also the postService:

```html
@Transactional
class PostService {

    def getPosts() {
        [allPosts:Post.list()]
    }
}
```

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

I am using windows 10 and chrome for the browser

Comment: I am surprised the first one works.  Are you saying that if you have a controller action named `list` and that action has 1 line of code in it, `def allPosts = postService.getPosts()`, that the GSP referencing `<g:each var="post" in="${allPosts}">` works?  I would expect `${postList}` to work, but not `${allPosts}`.  Just making sure I understand what you are saying.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown well allPosts is just a reference for the list, that points to the service getPosts() method.

Turns  out all I needed to do was put allPosts in the controller that wasn't working, into the else part of my if statement, where I was calling the profile to render the page, it was making allPosts null.

Comment: "it was making allPosts null" - That is exactly right.  The code that you showed would create a model variable named `postList`, not `allPosts`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to return from the service in this way

```
@Transactional
class PostService {

    def getPosts() {
        Post.list()
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is the model variable name.  This will have no impact.